# ASP.NET Webservice calling WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, service

I have almost the same problem as you have described in 
[Calling webservice from WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503242/calling-webservice-from-wcf-service).

I have a asp.net webservice that calls a WCF service. On my development machine this is working fine. But if i deploy my ASP.net Webservice it is not working. Both the ASP Webservice en WCF service needs my cridentials.

How did you solved your problem. In the logging of the WCF service I see that my credentials is not passing to WCF.

Please help. 
Regards,
Ozkan
o.ulu@deli-ict.nl

Comment: Can you provide more details on "it is not working"? Like, does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem was the application pool worker precess identity of service 1 that is calling service 2.

steps I used:
1 on server 1 add a new application pool
2 change the identity to a service account that can access service 2
3 add this account to IIS_WPG
4 Restart IIS on server 1

and it is working.